# How to make a Javascript namespace object which is also a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have all my javascript methods inside an `app` object so it works like a namespace e.g. app.init, app.sort... I want `app` to work also as a function, sort of like the jquery object, so I can call something like `app()`, or call one of its methods `app.method()`.

How can I do this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript you can treat functions as objects, like this:

```
function app(){
  alert('called');
}

app.init = function(){
  alert('you called a method of the app');
};

app();
app.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var app = function(){};

app.prototype.method = function() {
  alert("app.method has been called")
}

app.method();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with jQuery, you could also do this:

```
function yourMainFunction() {
  // code code code ...
}

$.extend(yourMainFunction, {
  something: "that looks like a 'namespace' definition",
  and: "so on"
});
```